# SSRS - Report Viewer Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ssrs-2008

When I want run the report viewer with Visual Studio, it cause the following error.

=========================================================================
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type
>   'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll'
>   and
>   'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL'

Source Error:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
       private global::Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer @__BuildControlReportViewerSummary() {
          global::Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer @__ctrl;
```

Is that mean i missing the .dll file ???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is totally unrelated to missing DLL file, instead it should related to same `ReportViewer` namespace exists in different DLL files at same directory (%Windows%\assembly). Try following solutions:

1. Check older version of `ReportViewer` in `_bin_deployableAssemblies` directory. Delete all files related to it, and use `Microsoft.ReportViewer.11.0` references.
2. Check duplicate declarations of `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` namespace in web.config file, remove older one if exists.
3. Add `qualifyAssembly` element in web.config file:

   ```
   <qualifyAssembly partialName="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" fullName="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms,version=11.0.0.0,culture=neutral,publicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
   ```
4. If the problem still persists, remove all references related to `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` namespace, clean entire solution (deleting DLL files referenced to older version), add new references with latest version then rebuild the solution file. Also, you may trying remove/uninstall one of conflicted DLL files from assembly directory.

NB: Remember that both versions (10.0 & 11.0) have different `PublicKeyToken` property value, hence `bindingRedirect` trick in `dependentAssembly` node doesn't work.

Related issues with CS0433:

[C#: The type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' exists in both ReportingServicesWebUserInterface.dll and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228197/c-the-type-microsoft-reporting-webforms-reportviewer-exists-in-both-reportin)

[The type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' exists in both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021808/the-type-microsoft-reporting-webforms-reportviewer-exists-in-both)